# Missing push notification entitlement, false positive for app

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

Please read this question completely without marking it as duplicate , I am now working on an app not using any API for Apple Push Notification.

And as far as testing goes, it works fine, but Apple keeps emailing me the message below.

I have read on the net, and done as much as I can to avoid this.
All i found on the internet having solution for this kind of problem for those who enables push notification but not a single solution for this false positive case.

My App ID is even not enabled for Push Notification, regenerating my Provisioning Profile (a number of times), with manual signing and …. But it keeps coming whatever I do. Am I missing some point? 
I've searched my app code for registerForRemoteNotifications and so far as I can tell I never attempt to register for push notifications.

Mail from Apple :-

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "myAPP". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode 8 does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

any help is appreciated,  this is rally important for me to fix this warning.
I have read on the net, and done as much as I can to avoid this.
All i found on the internet having solution for this kind of problem for those who enables push notification but not a single solution for this false positive case. i will be grateful for those with logical explanation to this issue.

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan have you read my question?, my app is not rejected, its accepted on appstore but still getting this warning mail from apple. and this warning is the problem.

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan please read the question carefully please please please. in your mention link, he is using push notification and in my case i am not using any notification.

Comment: did u find any solution for this? i am also not using PN still getting same warning, should i just ignore it? or there's a way? 
I have seen people mentioning that this warning doesn't rejects your app if you r not using PN...... whats ur take?

Answer (score 0):

this is a warning by apple that you have enable push notification for  particular App in your developer console .

But you have not enabled the push notification in your application 
Please go to your app target and enable this in capabilities and then try to upload

[image]

Disable Push notfication

Go to your Developer account 
Click on the app id for which you want to disable it 
[image]

then press edit 
and deselect the push notification in panel 
and save 
[image]

Then you have to again create new production certificates and upload the application.

Hope it helps

Comment: i dont need push notification then can you please share why i need to enable this in capability to fix this warning?

Comment: i tried with your way but NO luck, just want to confirm the need to create new certificate??? because i tried with re generating the provisioning and updating app ID but still getting that mail from apple for new release.

Comment: @ Anurag Soni ....Remove all your certificates from your mac and re create them and be sure not to include the push notification in App Id .....then be sure remove  push notification from every target in your application .....after doing this close your xcode and restart your system ....see if it works....recently i had issue uploading app on appstore got resolved after two without doing any change......

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well.

I just cleaned the build `Command + Option + Shift + K` and tried again, and it worked.

Sometimes you have to unselect and select your provisioning profiles in Xcode to make it work. I don't know why.

It is a pain trying different options out, as the process takes quite a bit of time.